# How can i publish and consume changes from thousands of tables from a RDBMS with Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

You have a RDBMS with thousands of tables (~9.000). Changes in these tables should be published to other consumers through Apache Kafka. I know Apache Nifi as a data routing and transformation tool from nearly any source. And i think about a graphical interface where i can select a table/object from the source system to publish the records to Apache Kafka. But how would a Change Data Capture of so many tables look like in Apache Nifi and also within Apache Kafka? Would i have to create ~9.000 processors (one for each table) and publish each of the tables to a dedicated topic per table? Or is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: make a process group that accepts flow file with table name as input. then you have just to trigger it 9K times for different tables

Comment: @daggett: And how would the Kafka side look like?

Comment: i don't know specifics & load for your process. but you could transfer all messages through 1 queue - table name could be a part of the message.

Comment: You can also use ListDatabaseTables to generate FlowFile(s) with the table names

Comment: I think you need to start from your source - and see if you can use the RDBMS logs to generate changes, similar to how the do replication. What is you RDBMS engine ?

Comment: Its Oracle 12.2